# Replace part of a character value in R

Tags: r

In my dataset (let's call it ds) I have a column with values formatted with a name followed by ".1" or ".2" where .1 and .2 mean yes or no. For example, something like:

Name
asth.1
asth.2
diabtd.1
diabtd.2

I want to replace ".1" and ".2" with something like "yes" and "no".

Is there an optimal way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `ds$Name <- sub(".1", ".yes", ds$Name); ds$Name <- sub(".2", ".no", ds$Name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using the tidyverse library.

```
library(tidyverse)
ds <- data.frame('asth.1','asth.2','diabtd.1','diabtd.2',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ds <- str_replace(ds, '.1', 'yes') 
ds <- str_replace(ds, '.2', 'no') 
ds
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a similar way to do it in base r? I'm new to R but have been told to try to limit the number of different packages I use

Comment: @aspiringrobot95 For a solution in base R see my comment above.

Comment: Agree with @RHertel.  That's part of the base package and works the same as the tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to create a new column with 'yes', 'no' based on the suffix values .1, .2, then extract the numbers, use that as index and then change it to 'yes', 'no'

```
c("yes", "no")[readr::parse_number(as.character(df1$Name)) * 10]
#[1] "yes" "no"  "yes" "no"
```

---

Or if we are want to replace the `.1` and `.2` with 'yes', 'no', then use `str_replace_all` with a named `vector`.  This methods also can take 'n' number of changes in a single step

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(df1$Name, setNames(c('yes', 'no'), c('.1', '.2'))
#[1] "asthyes"   "asthno"    "diabtdyes" "diabtdno"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("asth.1", "asth.2", "diabtd.1", "diabtd.2"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: The first solution is funny. Somewhat cryptic but definitely nice. Note however that it needs the data to be stored as characters, whereas the other one also works with factors.

Comment: @RHertel thanks, it is just that parse_number consider the `.` as part of numeric.  So, have to do that transformation :-).  I think the second option is difficult for an use case

Comment: Yes, I got that. It is a cool idea to transform ".1" and ".2" into indices 1 and 2 of a vector. What I meant is that `parse_number()` fails if `df1$Name` is stored as a factor.

Comment: @RHertel. you are right.  I will change with `as.character`